# How to use nextlink with OData V1?

Tags: c#, odata, dynamics-ax-2012

**TLDR; Question:** How do I consume an OData V1 Endpoint in C#?

I am trying to consume an OData V1 endpoint via `ODataClient` in C#, but I am unable to get all data pages.

The first set of results does include a next link:

```
<link rel="next" href="http://example.com/DynamicsAx/Services/OData/Lines?$skiptoken='AAEAAAD%...'" />
```

But if I try to get the Feed Annotations the library will generate a request like this:

```
GET https://example.com/DynamicsAx/Services/OData/Lines?$inlinecount=allpages
```

which will get this response back:

`Row counts cannot be requested when the MaxProtocolVersion of the data service is set to DataServiceProtocolVersion.V1.`